# Updating status of worker from class within the worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a worker that downloads a JSON from s3, then a streaming JSON parser (Oj Saj) that parses the file into my db. I can update the worker status from the worker's class, but once I am inside the parser class it is outside the scope of the worker (or so it appears to me)

```rb
class Worker

  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker



  class SajParser << Oj::Saj

    at 5 #this doesn't update the status of the worker

  end

  def perform()

    at 5 #this does update the status of the worker

  end

end
```

I would like a solution that allows me to update the status of the worker as the parsers goes over the JSON and inserts it into the db.

Comment: Yes you are right, the parser knows nothing about the internals of the worker. If you want them to share for example a counter then you must pass a reference form the worker to the parser instance. What is `at 5` doing? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: at is a method from the sidekiq status class that allows the pct_complete of a worker to be updated/stored. I was thinking about passing a reference into the class as arguments, but I don't know what needs to be passed. I could easily pass any of the worker info, but I none of that would allow me to access the scope where I can use the worker methods.

Comment: I think what I am going to do for the time being is save the pct_complete intermittently in the db. I feel it is a work around, but i'd rather have a working solution with potentially a little technical debt, then nothing at all. Unless anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make Sidekiq::Status `#at` method take the `jid` of the job to update and it's current status, then yes it is possible. Maybe you could follow up on this [issue](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status/issues/140) it seems the same as the one you have.

If I may suggest to actually use Sidekiq's power to parallelize the parser's job, into more workers instead of having one worker doing the job since you have the json in memory you can spin a job for each part of the json and whenever one of them is done, it should store its status somewhere accessible between all jobs like the DB for example.

Comment: I can't get the `#at` method to take a `jid`. That is something I investigated to no avail. I ended up just updating a column in the db and querying that column for the status of the job. To your last point. I am using a streaming parser to read the file without loading the file into memory to stay under a memory threshold. I'd love to parallelize it more, but, I can't see any other way other than to have multiple workers reading the same file, and looking for different tags, and doing certain actions based on what tag they are supposed to be looking for.

Comment: I opted to use a streaming parser as opposed to a DOM parser because the JSON files can be quite large( > 2gb) fairly easily.